# XAMPP HTTPS config show errors when start Apache

Tags: apache, https, server, port, block

I faced some strange problem.

Now I want to run https vhost apache server on my computer, so I set httpd.conf, httpd-ssl.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf.

But when run apache, it can't start and show below errors.

```
2:08:20 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
2:08:21 AM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
2:08:21 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
2:08:21 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:08:21 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:08:21 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:08:21 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:08:21 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
2:08:21 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

so I changed port as 4433, but there are same errors.

These are my configurations.

```
<VirtualHost my.com:4433>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/Work/Project/Source/public"
    ServerName my.com:4433
    ServerAlias my.com:4433
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/my/error.log
    CustomLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/my/access.log"
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "D:/Work/Project/Data/Certificate/server.cert"

    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/Work/Project/Data/Certificate/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also unblocked ports 443 and 4433.

Please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: So what does pressing that Logs button and checking the Windows Event Viewer reveal?

Comment: Oh and it should be `ServerName myclickhummer.com` without a port number. That name is invalid in its current format. Also you should not specify a `ServerAlias` which just specifies exactly the same name again.

Comment: Hello, @arkascha, Thanks. I changed ServerName as without a port number and remove ServerAlias but errors are same. :(

Comment: So that leaves you with the task to answer to my first comment ;-)

Comment: I checked error.log and Windows Event Viewer, but really there is no error related with this. :(

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt that. There certainly will be entries in the error log file if the server fails to start.

Comment: [Sun Nov 05 02:02:02.547343 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 21684:tid 620] AH01909: www.example.com:4433:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Nov 05 02:02:02.581867 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 21684:tid 620] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

This is last log, but error occurs about 02:55 :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158227/discussion-between-alex-and-arkascha).

Comment: Maybe seems related with httpd.conf or httpd-ssl.conf, but I don't know exactly...

Comment: If the server shuts down there has to be a reason and that is logged. Maybe you are looking at the wrong log file.

Comment: I also checked access.log and php_error.log but, there is nothing too ...

Comment: Hello, @arkascha, i fixed that error. that's because wrong log file path. but after than when i open https://myclickhummer.com:4433/   it still says 'Your connection is not private', can you let me know how can I fix this?

Comment: The later probably is because you are not using a valid ssl certificate in your server.

Comment: I make ssl certificate today according to this url. http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/apache-ssl-on-windows/   can you let me know may be need some more for ssl certificate?

Comment: A self signed certificate is not a "real" certificate in the sense that no browser will accept it without complaining. That does make a lot of sense. You can tell your browser that he has to accept it and it will obey. They you indeed should have an encrypted connection (unless your server setup is still wrong), but that will only work for you and you have no guarantee that the server responding really is your own server.

Comment: Right, I am connecting only myself now. But it is not working as I said. 'Your connection is not private'. Please let me know how I can connect as https exactly.

Comment: This depends a bit on your browser, each browser has its unique slang. But I dare say that this only indicates the issue with the certificate as mentioned above. If you _really_ want to test it then use a network sniffer and check the request. It should be encrypted. But there is nothing you can do about the certificate, except using a valid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.
ErrorLog and CustomLog is non existing path.

```
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/my/error.log
CustomLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/my/access.log"
```

After fixed that as below, it's working well.

```
ErrorLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/error.log"
TransferLog "C:/xampp/apache/logs/access.log"
```

Thanks!